# Understanding this recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

We are learning recursion in my intro to Java class, and I am having a hard time understanding how the method in the example given works. What is happening when the method is called?.

Here is the code:

```
public class Hanoi

    private int n;
    private int pegA;
    private int pegB;

    public Hanoi(int in_n, int in_pegA, int in_pegB)
    {
        n = in_n;
        pegA = in_pegA;
        pegB = in_pegB;
    }

    public void makemoves()
    {
        if (n==1)
            System.out.format("%d ==> %d%n", pegA, pegB)
        else
        { 
             int otherPeg = 6 - pegA - pegB; // 1 + 2 + 3 =6
             Hanoi firstmove = new Hanoi (n-1, pegA, otherPeg);
             firstmove.makemoves();
             System.out.format("%d ==> %d%n", pegA, pegB);
             Hanoi secondmove = new Hanoi (n-1, otherPeg, pegB);
             secondmove.makemoves();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems are you facing understand that? Did you try to trace that code?

Comment: You have to ask a specific question

Comment: What do you mean by tracing the code? Im having trouble understanding, line by line, what happens. 

So when firstmove.makemoves is called, does it immediately start over by making a new instance of Hanoi firstmove?

Or does it continue on to System.out.format, and then Hanoi secondmove, and then secondmove.makemoves(), before starting over?

Comment: Try to understand recursion (I'm assuming that is your concern) http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-189-a-gentle-introduction-to-programming-using-python-january-iap-2011/lectures/MIT6_189IAP11_rec_notes.pdf

Comment: @JamesChristopher. Yes. That is what happens. The best way to understand a code using Recursion, is to make use of `Stack`. Not in code, but on paper.

Comment: Try to ge piece of paper and write the output down.

Comment: @Rhohit Jain. So if it immediately starts over by making a new instance of Hanoi firstmove, then when does it get to System.out.format, and Hanoi secondmove?

Comment: @JamesChristopher.. When your current invocation returns, then the execution continues from the next line of the call that was made from.

Comment: @JamesChristopher.. When your current invocation returns, then the execution continues from the next line of the call that was made from.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is simply a method calling itself, and testing for a break condition.
This is an very easy example to illustrate the basic concept:

```
static void recurse( int val ) {
    if ( val == 0 ) {
        return; // returns from last invocation
    }
    System.out.println("val=" + val );
    recurse( val - 1 );
    return; // here the method returns to previous invocation (or initial call from main)
}


public static void main( String[] args) {
    recurse( 3 );
}
```

The first invocation recurse( 3 ) calls the method,
after testing that 3 != 0 the method calls itself with val - 1 until the value becomes 0.

The call hierachy looks like:

```
recurse( 3 )
  recurse( 2 )
    recurse( 1 )
      recurse( 0 ) // break condition
      return        // val == 0
    return          // val == 1
  return            // val == 2
return              // val == 3
```

Answer (score 0):

How this work is simply by traverse a binary tree in order. Check the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Towers_of_Hanoi).